# How to apply exact instead match by Nest api?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can I get `AEntity` where `BEntityProp` equals "Bprop 3"?

```cs
internal class Program
{
    public class AEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public BEntity BEntityProp { get; set; }
    }

    public class BEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Bprop { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "default_index");
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var entities = new List<AEntity>(100);

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            client.Index(new AEntity
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    BEntityProp =
                        new BEntity
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Bprop = "Bprop " + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        }
                });

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<AEntity>();

        //how to apply exact instead match by Nest api?
        List<AEntity> expected = client.Search<AEntity>(
            searchDescriptor.Query(qd => qd.Match(
                mqd => mqd.OnField(x => x.BEntityProp.Bprop).Query("bprop 3")))).Documents.ToList();

        try
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(expected.Count == 1);
        }
        finally 
        {
            client.DeleteIndex(di => di.Indices("default_index", "default_index" + "*"));
        }
    }
}
```

As a result I want to have 1 `AEntity` with Bprop equals "Bprop 3" but I have all matches "Bprop".

The request looks like:
expected :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": { <-- how to apply exact instead match by Nest api?
      "bEntityProp.bprop": {
        "query": "bprop 3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the ansvwer :

```
 List<AEntity> expected = client.Search<AEntity>(
            searchDescriptor.Query(qd => qd.MatchPhrase(
                mqd => mqd.OnField(x => x.BEntityProp.Bprop).Query("bprop 3")))).Documents.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact match then use a [Term](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query:

```cs
List<AEntity> expected = client.Search<AEntity>(
            searchDescriptor.Query(qd => qd.Term(
                mqd => mqd.OnField(x => x.BEntityProp.Bprop).Value("bprop 3"))))
                   .Documents.ToList();
```

More on Term vs Match can be found in this [discussion](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/term-query-vs-match-query-td4044500.html).

Comment: gsk, this approach returns me nothing